# JQuery For Download Button

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a project which is cropping uploaded image in circle and then save it for preview. Here is also a button for download saved image which is cropped.
Here is my main php page:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>PHP - jquery ajax crop image before upload using croppie plugins</title>
  <script src="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/croppie.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/bootstrap-3.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/croppie.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">Image Cropping Area</div>
   <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <div id="upload-demo" style="width:350px"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top:30px;">
    <strong>Select Image:</strong>
    <br/>
    <input type="file" id="upload">
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success upload-result">Upload Image</button>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="">
     <div id="upload-demo-i" style="background:#e1e1e1;width:300px;padding:30px;height:300px;margin-top:30px"></div>
     </div>
            <div>
    <a name="Download Save Image" id="download" download>Download Save Image</a>
</div>
    </div>

   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    viewport: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        type: 'circle'
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }
});

$('#upload').on('change', function () { 
 var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
     $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
      url: e.target.result
     }).then(function(){
      console.log('jQuery bind complete');
     });
     
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
 $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
  type: 'canvas',
  size: 'viewport'
 }).then(function (resp) {

  $.ajax({
   url: "ajaxpro.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {"image":resp},
   success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                if (response.image) {
                    html = '<img id="preview" src="' + response.image + '" />';
                    $("#upload-demo-i").html(html);
                    $('#download').attr({
                        target: '_blank',
                        href: response.image
                    })
                }else {
                    alert('Failed to upload image');
                }
    
   }
  });
 });
});





</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the other for ajax is:

```html
$data = $_POST['image'];

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

$data = base64_decode($data);
$imageName = time().'.png';
if (file_put_contents('upload/' . $imageName, $data)) {
    echo json_encode(['image' => 'upload/' . $imageName]); // upload is successful and we return image URL to Javascript
}else {
    echo json_encode(['image' => false]); // if upload fails
}
```

Its functionality is simple and working well.I tried hard to make a simple downloadable button but never found suitable JQuery. Now I am looking for JQuery for my download button to download cropped image. Kindly guide me what part of code I have to put and where.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: when you say download you mean using ajax?

Comment: yes thats right... i have ajax page also to display cropped result

Comment: Do you try to add a link with download attr? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: well i tried to use it for my div area also but when i insert my cropped image display blocked... Can you show me how can i use it in this portion...       <div class="col-md-4" style="">
     <div id="upload-demo-i" style="background:#e1e1e1;width:300px;padding:30px;height:300px;margin-top:30px"></div>
     </div>

Comment: @AngelFragnance how is your PHP for uploading the image?

Comment: @julekgwa i include my ajax page code also which is working to upload image... kindly have a look on it also

Comment: @AngelFragnance please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your Download image button to `<a>` and given it an id of `download` and used [HTML5 download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) to force file download

```
<div>
    <a name="Download Save Image" id="download" download>Download Save Image</a>
</div>
```

Your `PHP`

```
$data = $_POST['image'];

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

$data = base64_decode($data);
$imageName = time().'.png';

if (file_put_contents('upload/' . $imageName, $data)) {
    echo json_encode(['image' => 'upload/' . $imageName]); // upload is successful and we return image URL to Javascript
}else {
    echo json_encode(['image' => false]); // if upload fails
}
```

Then in your `AJAX` get the image URL and set it to the download anchor tag by adding the `href` and `target` attributes.

```
$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (resp) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxpro.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"image": resp},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                if (response.image) {
                    html = '<img id="preview" src="' + response.image + '" />';
                    $("#upload-demo-i").html(html);
                    $('#download').attr({
                        target: '_blank',
                        href: response.image
                    })
                }else {
                    alert('Failed to upload image');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried you code as you can check i update my above but its not working... it did not show me cropped image when i click on upload image button. also when i click on "download save image" button, its also do nothing... kindly check my updated code again and let me know if i place your code on right way.

Comment: no there is no error...but buttons are also not working

Comment: please right click on download and inspect element and check if `href` is empty

Comment: yes it is empty because your code to save/crop image is not working.... first we have to look that when we click on upload button it must show cropped image... as my previous functions was working...

Comment: the code is working for me, which browser are you using?

Comment: i checked for upload button console and it give me error like below 
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (localhost/:78)
    at fire (jquery.js:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:1148)
    at done (jquery.js:8074)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:8598)
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/bootstrap.min.css.map

Comment: are you on linux or windows?

Comment: i am using chrome Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)

Comment: here is my index.php [link](https://codeshare.io/2polAE)      here is my ajax.php [link](https://codeshare.io/2BMWdy)

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: kindly check my new [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986625/all-device-friendly-php-page)

Comment: Here my friend facing a problem. Kindly view this question and try to fix errors [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893082/linkedin-create-post-issues) Thanks :)